# IQueryable object contains 5 object but displays nothing when we call it

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, iqueryable

I have a problem with my Web API service. I'm getting a list of `Societe` objects from the database, and I would like to let the web service return the data in JSON. To do this, I created the following method in my `SocieteController`:

```
// GET api/Societe
public IQueryable<Societe> GetSociete()
{
    SocieteManager manager = new SocieteManager(db);
    List<Societe> listeSociete = manager.getAllSociete();
    return listeSociete.AsQueryable();            
}
```

When I call the URI `api/Societe`, I get 5 empty JSON brackets. It looks like the service got the objects and knows how many there are, but it can't show them.

When I debug, I can see that `listeSociete` contains 5 `Societe` objects.

Any idea what's going on? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

LINQ queries are not immediately executed, which is commonly known as [*deferred execution*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx). Try adding the `ToList()` extension method at the end of the sequence:

```
return listeSociete.AsQueryable().ToList();
```

You can probably drop the `AsQueryable()` call, so the line becomes:

```
return listeSociete.ToList();
```

Also, could be that you'll have to return `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IQueryable<T>`. All examples I've seen and implemented with Web API 2 return `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: This is correct, unless he wants to use it as OData service

Comment: I have tried what you've said but it shows me the same result. Empty brackets !

Comment: Have you also changed the method's return type to `IEnumerable<Societe>`? Which version of Web API are you using?

Comment: Yes and all of yours answers are correct. It was my fault, the getters of Societe class were not properly written.

Comment: @AD.Net its only half correct. OP should change his `SocieteManager` to return a real IQueryable, which will avoid pulling down his entire database each call.

Comment: @Aron, yes you're correct. It should not be a IQueryable on a List<T>